# Why Javascript is not getting called

Tags: javascript

Javascript code is

```
function jsCheck() {
var msg = '';

//Move email checker to first line of javascript validation
if (document.form1.email.value.indexOf(".") <= 3  && document.form1.email.value.indexOf("@") <= 2){ msg = msg + 'Valid Email Address\n'; }
if (document.form1.name.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Full Name\n'; }
if (document.form1.company.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Company Name\n'; }
if (document.form1.telephone.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Telephone No\n'; }
if (document.form1.country.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Country\n'; }

if (msg != ''){
alert('The following fields are missing\n\n' + msg);
return false;
}

form name="form1" method="post" action="apply_confirm.asp" onSubmit="return jsCheck();"
```

Why the javascript is not getting called

Comment: dude! cut down the code to just some sample, we don't need the whole page. Explain what happens/doesn't happen. And please write something a bit nicer than "as soon as possible".

Comment: Tarun, you just experienced the full force of Monday across the world! :P

Answer (score 5):

Well, if your original posting is accurate (a number of things have changed as people have attempted to make your post legible), it's because everything you posted is enclosed in HTML comments, `<!-- ... -->`.

And yeah, as far as providing the solution as soon as possible goes, you might want to keep in mind that we don't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have an error in your javascript code.

1. Test your javascript in [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com).

   - Open the error console with CTRL+SHIFT+J or **Tools** -> **Error Console**.
   - Look for an error message or warning explaining the javascript error.
   - If you are unsure what the error message means, add it to the question so we can explain it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsCheck() {
var msg = '';

//Move email checker to first line of javascript validation
if (document.form1.email.value.indexOf(".") <= 3  && document.form1.email.value.indexOf("@") <= 2){ msg = msg + 'Valid Email Address\n'; }
if (document.form1.name.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Full Name\n'; }
if (document.form1.company.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Company Name\n'; }
if (document.form1.telephone.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Telephone No\n'; }
if (document.form1.country.value == ""){ msg = msg + 'Country\n'; }

if (msg != ''){
alert('The following fields are missing\n\n' + msg);
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="apply_confirm.asp" onSubmit="return jsCheck();">
<input type='text' id='name'/>
<input type='text' id='company'/>
<input type='text' id='email'/>
<input type='text' id='telephone'/>
<input type='text' id='country'/>
<input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for effort, Hardly likely that the poster will select an "answer" from the collective here.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_nodes_access.asp